# Why during first boot my navigation bar is under status bar

Tags: swift, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, ios10

Why when I create navigation controller with empty view controller I receive strange behaviour with navigation bar?

This is how I create navigation controller.

```
init(
    window: UIWindow,
    keystore: Keystore,
    navigationController: UINavigationController = UINavigationController()
) {
    self.navigationController = navigationController
    self.keystore = keystore
    super.init()
    window.rootViewController = navigationController
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Than I simply do :

```
func start() {
    let x = UIViewController()
    x.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    navigationController.setViewControllers([x], animated: true)
}
```

And I receive:
[image]
But in the next app launches all is fine.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be the case, because you set the NavigationController after the app has already started.

I would recommend to set the NavigationController in your AppDelegate.

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

        let firstViewController = UIViewController()
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: firstViewController)

        window?.rootViewController = navigationController
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: The main issue was in UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds) in my case it was UIWindow()